# Do Office.js Add-ins always take a 32-bit Internet Explorer process as a host on Windows?

Tags: office-js

We are developing Excel content and task pane add-ins with Office.js. According to our scenario, the user might add a lot of content add-ins to this Excel workbook. I have tested it on Windows and found out that adding the first add-in to Excel launches a 32-bit and a 64-bit Internet Explorer 11 processes in the background, however by adding extra add-ins, the memory usage of this single 32-bit IE process grows only.

Image: addins consume memory of the 32-bit Internet Explorer process only
[image]

This is very unfortunate and it means a hard limit to our development as some of our content add-ins might consume a considerable amount of memory and their host 32-bit process can access a maximum of 2GB of RAM only (in practice, Internet Explorer 11 stops working after it allocates ~1.4 GB of memory).

We are using 64-bit Office (Version 1707, Build 8326.2076 Click-to-Run) on Windows 10 (10.0.15063).

Is there a way to launch a 64-bit Internet Explorer process as the host of our add-ins instead of a 32-bit process? Or can we start separate host processes for every addin?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control which browser engine is loaded by Office. Note that each platform uses it's own engine. For Office for Windows it uses an embedded IE instance, Office for Mac and Office for iPad use an embedded WebKit browser, Chrome/IE/Edge/Safari/Firefox use an IFRAME.

I'm more concerned about the "considerable amount of memory" requirement. You should really take a look at [Resource usage limits for add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/resource-limits-and-performance-optimization#resource-usage-limits-for-add-ins). Add-ins should be quick and responsive. Generally you should be doing as much intensive processing as possible on the server-side with the add-in handling communication and UX rendering on the client-side.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Marc. In one of our use-cases we should support adding around 100 content add-ins to a massive Excel workbook or to a PowerPoint presentation across multiple sheets / slides. In the current state of our development, the memory requirement of an average content add-in is around 80 MB (using AngularJs and Kendo UI with other third party libraries), so now approximately 15-20 add-ins can be placed into one document. In general do you have any patterns / methods / suggestions for implementing such amount of add-ins?